# What is meant by $$$var. IS it works in php

Tags: php

I know what is **`$var`** and `$$var` will do. But in an interview they give me a problem which contains `$$$var`. What is that means actually. I cant find any reference for that.

Comment: Variable of variables.. Show us the problem

Comment: You can say it nested variables of variables

Comment: Like i said  i found it on a online interview test. So don't have a backup.

Comment: thanks . i got it by searching "nested variables of variables".

Comment: @shoaib see my answer below so you can understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). This will make you understand:

```
<?php
$a = 123;
$b = 'a';
$var = 'b';
echo $var;    //b
echo $$var;   //a
echo $$$var;  //123
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can understand the flow:

`$var` is a variable and it hold value.

`$$var` means the new variable that name is the value of `$var`.

and `$$$var` means the new variable that name is the value of `$$var`.

**example:**

```
$var = 'app';
```

so `$$var`  will be `$app`.

and so on.